# growing list of strings using the string input len as the index to place the string

Tags: python

I am trying to get a growing list of strings, with each subsequent string input, place that string in the index equal to its length and then return the new combined string (as a string) after n amount of inputs. Here is what I have far...

````py
# user input number of elements
user_input_count = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

# repeat counter
repeat_counter = 1

while repeat_counter < user_input_count:
    user_input_string = input(f"Enter the value of input #{repeat_counter}: ")
    split_string_list = list(user_input_string)
    print(f"output: {split_string_list}")
    print(repeat_counter)
    while repeat_counter < user_input_count:
        repeat_counter += 1
        new_input_string = input(f"Enter the value of input #{repeat_counter}: ")
        x = list(new_input_string)
        split_string_list.insert(len(new_input_string), x)
        print(split_string_list)```
````

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: how would I get the growing list of strings to output correctly. an example would be first word is "word", second word would be hi, and the combined word would be wohird. Continue that as many times based on the number the user inputed at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is storing your inputs in a 2d-list. The first dimension is the length of the strings. The second dimension is a list of strings that belong to the length.

**The list looks like this:**

```
split_string_list = [[],["a","b],["ab","ac"],["abc"]] #etc.
```

**The code:**

```
# user input number of element

user_input_count = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

# repeat counter
repeat_counter = 1
split_string_list = []
concatenated_string = ""

for counter in range(0, user_input_count):
    user_input_string = input(f"Enter the value of input #{repeat_counter}: ")
    concatenated_string += user_input_string
    list_length = len(split_string_list)
    # this if you want to append the concatenated string to the list
    # string_length = len(concatenated_string)
    # else
    string_length = len(user_input_string)

    if string_length > list_length:
        # make the list longer so that it can fit the new string at index of length
        split_string_list += ([] for x in range(string_length - list_length + 1))

    # append it at the index of the length of the string
    split_string_list[string_length].append(user_input_string)
    # this line if you wish to append the concatenated string instead
    # split_string_list[len(concatenated_string) ].append(concatenated_string)

    print(split_string_list)

    # call the last element (the newest element within a subarray) of the list
    print(f"output: {split_string_list[string_length][-1]}")
    print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get the results I wanted with the code snippet below...

```py
# user input number of elements
user_input_count = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

# repeat counter
repeat_counter = 1

while repeat_counter < user_input_count:
    user_input_string = input(f"Enter the value of input #{repeat_counter}: ")
    split_string_list = list(user_input_string)
    print(f"output: {split_string_list}")
    print(repeat_counter)
    while repeat_counter < user_input_count:
        repeat_counter += 1
        new_input_string = input(f"Enter the value of input #{repeat_counter}: ")
        x = list(new_input_string)
        split_string_list.insert(len(new_input_string), x)
        flat_list = [item for sublist in split_string_list for item in sublist]
        print(*flat_list, sep="")
```

I will be totally honest, the code doesn't seem that great meaning that it could probably be optimized and shortened by a lot. One part that seems redundant is the nested while loop.